# How to select a nth-child of an id with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to select a nth-child of a div with an id with the help of jquery.
This is my markup:

```
<div id="burger-wrapper" onclick="menu()">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
</div>
```

And this is the jquery-selector:

```
let firstBurgerSpan = $("#burger-wrapper span:nth-child(1)");
```

But the selected span is "undefined". Am I missing something or is this the wrong way to select these spans?

EDIT:

[This is the output i get when i console-log the selector first, and then try to change the style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqVW3.png)

Comment: Is your jQuery executed after the HTML has been loaded?

Comment: Your code is fine, just on wrong place.

Comment: Are you sure the have added the jQuery scripts in `head` of the page ?

Comment: Try this one $( "#burger-wrapper" ).children()[1];

Comment: Would `span:nth-of-type` not be better? `span:nth-child` will start to fail once children have different tagnames.

Comment: `But the selected span is "undefined"` this is not possible. A jQuery object is never undefined, even if the selector didn't match anything in the DOM

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, maybe OP is already trying to get the first element of the result, so the result would be undefined.

Comment: i think you selected the right thing, but you are not doing anything with it, an empty span results in nothing when logging it, insert a letter or number in there and a log will show that input inside the span. this explains what i mean: https://jsfiddle.net/h2pxg9vf/1/

Comment: Other jquery selectors are perfectly working. 
And the exact error I am getting is "Cannot set property 'transform' of undefined" when I am trying to change the style of the span.

Comment: Well, show the code which actually provides the error. Most likely it is a messed  up handling/accessing of *jquery/non-query*. `transform` is a property of `style`, unless used in SVGElements.

Comment: OP, have you considered @swiftlynx's comment? Are you certain the HTML has been loaded before your script is executed?

Comment: I dont think thats the case. I have edited the post so you can see the two outputs. I think the answer below might provide the answer tho.

Comment: You are probably trying `$("#burger-wrapper span:nth-child(1)").style.transform;`. jQuery objects offer no property `style` which makes it `undefined` and leads to **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transform' of undefined**. Either use `$("#burger-wrapper span:nth-child(1)").get(0).style.transform;` or the jQuery equivalent.

Comment: @Lain Yeah thats correct, that was the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the actual span, you have to take (`get`) it like:
`firstBurgerSpan.get(0)`. Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9q3b8mgc/)

Comment: Your answer statement is still wrong. Just FYI. It does not give the `array` back (well technically yes) it give your exact element you searched for. which is first span and you can use jQuery functions to do whatever you want from that element. there is not is not need to use `[0]`

Comment: @AlwaysHelping then the fiddle must be wrong. Code written against jQuery 3.4.1.

Comment: `firstBurgerSpan[0]` provides the DOM-Element and is equal to jquery `firstBurgerSpan.get(0)`. What your fiddle logs is therefore the DOM-Element and not the jquery wrapped object. So yeah, to actually get the `span` the example is correct, just the array part is misleading.

Comment: I don't know how this is flagged as correct. The variable just needs to use the ```>``` selector method. The variable is undefined so don't even bother trying to access the method.

Comment: @destroyer22719 that is incorrect. Whether to use `>` to prevent more potential depth is up to the OP, his structure and his requirements.

Answer (score -1):

Just to add, the jQuery solution actually would be:

```
$("#burger-wrapper span:nth-child(1)").css('transform', '...');
```

```js
$("#burger-wrapper span:nth-child(1)").css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="burger-wrapper">
      <span>1</span>
      <span>2</span>
      <span>3</span>
</div>
```

Do not mix up jQuery and non-jQuery unnecessarily. Else you can as good skip jQuery all together to achieve this:

```
document.querySelector("#burger-wrapper > span:nth-child(1)").style.transform = '...';
```

```js
document.querySelector("#burger-wrapper span:nth-child(1)").style.color = 'blue';
```

```html
<div id="burger-wrapper">
      <span>1</span>
      <span>2</span>
      <span>3</span>
</div>
```

> You are probably trying `$("#burger-wrapper span:nth-child(1)").style.transform;`. jQuery objects offer no
> property `style` which makes it `undefined` and leads to **Uncaught
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'transform' of undefined**. Either use
> `$("#burger-wrapper span:nth-child(1)").get(0).style.transform;` or
> the jQuery equivalent.

Comment: this is not css and that will still return undefined. You need to use ```#id > tagname``` to select the child.

Comment: @destroyer22719: Looks all correct to me. Added you working snippets to show that it works.

Comment: @destroyer22719: `>` does not matter in this case and is up to the choice of InsertIntoHTL.

Answer (score -2):

```
 let firstBurgerSpan = $("#burger-wrapper span:nth-child(1)");
```

that one is wrong and I don't see anyone else mentioning the fact that you have a simple selector problem. You need to use the `.find()` method or the child selector method `>`

```
let firstBurgerSpan = $("#burger-wrapper > span:nth-child(1)");
```

or

```
let firstBurgerSpan = $("#burger-wrapper").find ("span:nth-child(1)");
```

Comment: `$("#burger-wrapper").find("span:nth-child(1)")` is the same as `$("#burger-wrapper span:nth-child(1)")`. `$("#burger-wrapper").children("span:nth-child(1)")` would be the same as `$("#burger-wrapper > span:nth-child(1)")`. All work fine in this specific case.